# Which SharePoint Authentication Mode Should I be using for this scenario?

Tags: sharepoint, authentication

I currently have a sharepoint 2010 site for which NTLM windows authentication has been enabled (by default it is against Active Directory I believe).

I'd need to change this so that I have 1 custom login page which accepts username/password/domain and validates those information against the active directory, then if that was valid, I'll write logic to logon to another webservice which is located on another server and returns me a unique sessionId that I can store (as a cookie) for further use.

Please could you advise which authentication mode I can use to create this custom login page? should that be FBA against AD? not sure how that works.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

yeah you have to use claim based FBA authentication that will use ldap membership provided follow the below link for LDAP configuration

[Configure forms-based authentication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806890.aspx)